# web2py tutorial failing to produce a prompt

Tags: web2py

I am using Web2py version 2.16.1-stable_timestmap.2017.11.14.05.54.25.

I am working through the tutorial where you add first() and second() to demonstrate making a form entry and displaying an entered value.  I am not getting a prompt for the name. It looks just like it did for the first sample web page **"Hello from MyApp!"**

I have created functions **first** and **second** in the default controller. Note: the book does not say *where* to put this. I have placed them after function **index** but at the same level of indentation as function **index**.  My entries

```
def first():
    return dict()

def second():
    return dict()
```

As instructed, I have created views/default/first.html and views/default/second.html in views.

The views/default.first.html file

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h1>What is your name?</h1>
<form action="second">
    <input name="visitor_name" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The views/default/second.html file

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h1>Hello {{=request.vars.visitor_name}}</h1>
```

As stated, when I go to the apps default index page, I get the same response that I got before this section of the tutorial, just Hello from MyApp.

I have closed and reopened the browser. I have closed and restarted Web2py and opened a new browser. No change in behavior.

Note: when I run the link to MyApp, I get no errors in the server command window, but there is an error there when I start:

```
starting browser...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\web2py_win\web2py\gluon\admin.py", line 341, in check_new_version
version = to_native(urlopen(version_url).read())
File "urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
File "urllib.py", line 213, in open
File "urllib.py", line 350, in open_http
File "httplib.py", line 997, in endheaders
File "httplib.py", line 850, in _send_output
File "httplib.py", line 812, in send
File "httplib.py", line 793, in connect
File "socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
```

followed by an IO connection error.

Is this error related or have I done something else wrong?

Why am I not getting the prompt "What is your name?"

This is about as simple as it gets. If I can't get past example, I'm going nowhere with web2py.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. The book example, a viewed as a PDF, has the URL so small, I could not see that the URL was no longer default/index.html but is now default/first.html. Going to that different page results in the specified prompt.